# Не видит переменную $row

Tags: php, html

```html
<php
 $rows = db_select_all("select
            ms.id,
   ifnull((select title from meetings mt where mt.id = ms.meet_id and mt.deleted = 0), null) as meet,
   ifnull((select title from meet_role mr where mr.id = ms.role_id and mr.deleted = 0), null) as role,
   ifnull((select title from meet_item i where i.id = ms.item_id and i.deleted = 0), null) as item,
   ifnull((select title from meet_status m where m.id = ms.staff_status and m.deleted = 0), null)  as status
        from meet_staff ms
        where ms.staff_id= {$objid}"); 

?>
  <table class="grid">
   <col width="25%">
   <col width="25%">
   <col width="25%">
   <col width="25%">
   <tr>
    <th>Совещание:</th>
    <th>Вопрос:</th>
    <th>Роль:</th>
    <th>Статус:</th>
   </tr>
    <? foreach ($rows as $row) { ?>
   <tr>
    <td> <?=$row['meet']?></td>
    <td><?=$row['item']?></td>
    <td><?=$row['role']?></td>
    <td><?=$row['status']?></td>
   </tr>
   <? } ?> 
  </table>
```

Выдает ошибку [8:notice] Undefined variable: row 
Пробовала разные варианты, но как-то не выхоит

Comment: `<php` исправьте на `<?php`, и удалите вопрос, пока никто не видел :)

Comment: Там <?php стоит, случайно так перепечатала :)

Comment: да тут и ошибка про `row` а не `rows`, оказывается..

Comment: `<? foreach ($rows as $row) { 
    echo '<tr><td>'.$row['meet'].'</td><td>'.$row['item'].'</td><td>'.$row['role'].'</td><td>'.$row['status'].'</td></tr>';
   } ?>  `   Пробовала такой вариант, но выводит в табличку `$row['meet']` , а не значение этой перемнной.

Comment: дак у вас похоже короткие тэги ([short_open_tag](http://php.net/manual/ru/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)) не работают тогда?

Comment: `<?=$row['item']?>` был доступен,а `<? foreach` нет, отсюда и ошибка. я было хотел раньше это предложить, думал что `<?=` включается вместе с короткими тэгами, а оно оказывается отдельно.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы не было кривотолков, к данному коду надо было приписать всего лишь 6 букв - вместо `<?` везде написать `<?php`

```
      <?php foreach ($rows as $row) { ?>
     <tr>
         <td> <?=$row['meet']?></td>
         <td><?=$row['item']?></td>
         <td><?=$row['role']?></td>
         <td><?=$row['status']?></td>
     </tr>
     <?php } ?>
```

Больше ничего трогать в этом коде не нужно было.

Answer (score 0):

```html
?>
  <table class="grid">
    <col width="25%">
   <col width="25%">
   <col width="25%">
   <col width="25%">
  <?php
   echo "<tr>
    <th>Совещание:</th>
    <th>Вопрос:</th>
    <th>Роль:</th>
    <th>Статус:</th>
   </tr>";
     foreach ($rows as $row) { 
    echo "<tr><td>".$row['meet']."</td><td>".$row['item']."</td><td>".$row['role']."</td><td>".$row['status']."</td></tr>";
   } 
 ?>
 </table>;
```

Решила проблему так.

Comment: а надо было решать так как сказано выше - `<?php` вместо `<?`

Answer (score -1):

У вашем случае нужно использовать **альтернативный синтаксис** php. Для этого конструкцию:

```
foreach($items as $item){
    #code;
}
```

Нужно заменить на конструкцию вида:

```
foreach($items as $item):
    #code;
endforeach();
```

Для вашего примера это будет выглядеть так:

```html
   
 <?php
 $rows = db_select_all("select
            ms.id,
   ifnull((select title from meetings mt where mt.id = ms.meet_id and mt.deleted = 0), null) as meet,
   ifnull((select title from meet_role mr where mr.id = ms.role_id and mr.deleted = 0), null) as role,
   ifnull((select title from meet_item i where i.id = ms.item_id and i.deleted = 0), null) as item,
   ifnull((select title from meet_status m where m.id = ms.staff_status and m.deleted = 0), null)  as status
        from meet_staff ms
        where ms.staff_id= {$objid}"); 

?>
  <table class="grid">
   <col width="25%">
   <col width="25%">
   <col width="25%">
   <col width="25%">
   <tr>
    <th>Совещание:</th>
    <th>Вопрос:</th>
    <th>Роль:</th>
    <th>Статус:</th>
   </tr>
    <?php foreach ($rows as $row): ?>
   <tr>
    <td> <?=$row['meet']?></td>
    <td><?=$row['item']?></td>
    <td><?=$row['role']?></td>
    <td><?=$row['status']?></td>
   </tr>
   <?php endforeach; ?> 
  </table>
```

Более детально про альтернативный синтаксис можно почитать [здесь](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

Comment: Что за бред? при чем здесь альтернативный синтаксис?

Comment: Хочешь сказать что код с фигурными дужками будет работать в данном примере?

Comment: А ты хочешь сказать что в пхп фигурные скобки не работают? Это очень смелое заявление.

Comment: В **данном примере** они работать не будут. Здесь либо безобразное `foreach ($rows as $row) { echo "<tr><td>".$row['meet']."</td><td>".$row['item']."</td><td>".$row['role']."</td><td>".$row['status']."</td></tr>"; }` , либо красиво с использованием альтернативного синтаксиса.

Comment: Да и альтернативный синтаксис создан для работы в представлении. Так что скорее бред говорить, что он здесь не при чем.